# Using a variable for dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I'm building a table that has two cells of the same class but of different identifiers.

I am using a segmented control to display either or.

I believe everything is hooked up properly on Storyboard, however,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let friendRequest = self.friendRequestsToDisplay[indexPath.row]

    requestDirection = isAnIncomingRequest ? "IncomingRequestCell" : "OutgoingRequestCell"

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(requestDirection) as? RequestCell {

        cell.configureCell(friendRequest, isAnIncomingRequest: isAnIncomingRequest)

        return cell

    } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

**FAILS AT** `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, according to breakpoints, with:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

After hard coding the Identifiers (`"IncomingRequestCell"` and `"OutgoingRequestCell"` in the `dequeueReusable...` method as suggested in the comments, it appears that these values are the source of the problem. However, they properly identify their respective UITableViewCells in IB.

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess `friendRequest` is `nil`

Comment: Are you sure `isAnIncomingRequest` is non-nil? The only two optional variables in the code shown are `friendRequest` and `isAnIncomingRequest`. I would unwrap these using an `if let` statement first before using them. Use the debugger and step through your code checking the value of your optionals. By the way, using a force-unwrap is a bad idea as you will crash if the variable is nil.

Comment: @vadian it isn't, just placed a print statement after and returns the right value

Comment: Then `isAnIncomingRequest` is `nil`. What's the purpose to declare a boolean as optional?

Comment: neither are nil and neither are optionals. I printed them all out @vadian

Comment: The code you posted has you unwrapping them with !. They are optionals.

Comment: When they print out, because they are force unwrapped, they do not print out optional @BeauYoung So they exist...

Comment: Just do the above suggestion first. You shouldn't be force unwrapping anyway, but just throw them in an `if let`. Do as suggested, you can change it back later.

Comment: @BeauYoung the `friendRequest` doesn't matter though because the line that crashes is `dequeueReusableCell...` Nonetheless I followed suggestions and am still getting `fatal ... found nil while unwrapping`

Comment: I think you might have to post some more code.

Comment: @BeauYoung just edited the question, what more should I post? The only variable in the line that fails is `requestDirection`

Comment: Does it work if you hard code "IncomingRequestCell" or "OutgoingRequestCell" in dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier? Just to test.

Comment: @BeauYoung no it does not, i was just testing that! Just edited my question. Any ideas?

Comment: All out of ideas. The only reason I can see why dequeue would be failing is due to a nil `requestDirection`. If it can't create the cell, it should just fall back into the `else` section of your code.

Comment: Try this `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("IncomingRequestCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RequestCell` note the `indexPath` in use here.

Comment: @BeauYoung That crashed as well. Out of curiosity, do you need to have a matching class for each identifier? Because I am sharing one class for the two identifiers `RequestCell`

Comment: No you don't otherwise there's be no point having identifiers if you could just tell them apart from their classes. I'm sorry, I don't have a clue on how to solve your issue. Usually the steps we have just taken, work for me. Last thing I could suggest is trying to create a plain UITableViewCell. Maybe the crash is occurring when trying to init your `RequestCell`.

Comment: @BeauYoung Because when I delete the `"OutgoingRequestCell"` from Storyboard and hardcode `"IncomingRequestCell"`, it crashes. However, when I reidentify it as `"RequestCell"` (class name) it works....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you use global variable for `reuseIdentifier` and update it every time? You can use local var for it.

Also avoid using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, please use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` instead. I had some strange issues in one of my previous project because of it.

Here is quick example, which works like a charm:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let identifier = (indexPath.row == 0) ? "Cell1" : "Cell2"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    self.configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

UPDATE: After investigation, we figured, that problem was in custom cell class initialization code.

Comment: Still doesn't work...... Also, I'd like to know if there's a reason in particular you are passing `indexPath` to your `configureCell` function?

Comment: @rayjohn this is just updated code from new project template, `configureCell` initially takes `indexPath` parameter.

Comment: @rayjohn did you change from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` and tried to use local variable for reusable identifier?

Comment: yes I did, `requestDirection` is now declared within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and I have updated to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(requestDirection, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? ...`. However, this line still crashes.

Comment: Did you sure, that you registered your cells `IncomingRequestCell` and second one in the table view with `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`?

Comment: ! Nope, I haven't done that. Is this a requirement if I plan on using multiple identifiers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94557/discussion-between-vitaliy-gozhenko-and-ray-john).

Comment: also problem can be in your custom cell class initialization

Answer (score 0):

If everything is hooked up properly - which means that you correctly set your `reuseIdentifiers`in IB and the `UITableViewCells` are prototyp cells within your `UITableView` (and **not** loaded from a nib - which requires manually registering the `UITableViewCells`), than just use

```
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:
```